# Graph equality vs. graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, definition, graph-isomorphism

Need help understanding a fundamental concept.

Let's consider only the set $V =\{1,2,3,4\}$. Suppose I have two graphs $G,G'$:
$$G = \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}\qquad G' = \{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\} $$ 
It is obvious these graphs are isomorphic. One possible isomorphism
$$1\mapsto 2,\quad 2\mapsto 1,\quad 3\mapsto 3,\quad 4\mapsto 4 $$

Inspired by [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945406/isomorphism-vs-equality-of-graphs) a comment under the main post reads as follows: "..As far as I know, two graphs are equal iff they are isomorphic..."

But I just expressed my two graphs as sets and these sets are NOT equal hence these graphs, although isomorphic, are also not equal. I don't know what to believe.

Furthermore, if we say "distinct graphs of $n$ vertices" do we in fact say graphs that are NOT equal?

EDIT: Fixed hyperlink, didn't even notice :(

Comment: I've added another answer to this old question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945406/isomorphism-vs-equality-of-graphs/4015245#4015245 , hoping that it could provide some useful ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, graph theory does not *care* about mere differences in how you label the nodes, so from a graph-theoretic point of view, your $G$ and $G'$ *are* "the same" graph. This is what the concept of **isomorphic graphs** expresses.

On the other hand, $G$ and $G'$ are *represented by* different set-theoretic objects, so it can be confusing to call them "equal", even though the difference between them is not one we care about.

It is nevertheless somewhat common in many areas of mathematics to use the word "equal" about structures that are merely isomorphic, if one has faith that the reader/listener will understand (or guess) that what one really means is "isomorphic". Sometimes that faith is misplaced. Use this language at your own risk.

---

The two graphs are, however, clearly different as **subgraphs** of $K_4$, though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This question is brought about a problem on asymmetric graph $G$ of $n$ vertices for which it is sufficient (and necessary) that $n!$ distinct graphs are isomorphic to $G$.
..but isomorphism is an equivalence relation, so if they are all isomorphic it automatically means they are all equal. Makes no sense!

Comment: @AlvinLepik: I agree that "so-and-so many distinct graphs are isomorphic to $G$" does not make sense -- at least absent an explicit specification of what counts as "distinct" in this context.