# Line graph $L(G)$ is bipartite if and only if the graph is isomorphic to path or even cycle.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph.

[Line Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) $L(G)$ is bipartite if and only if the graph is isomorphic to path or even cycle.

I have shown that if the graph is a path or even cycle then the line graph is bipartite.

I am having difficulty in proving the other part.

Comment: By the way, why do you need "isomorphic" in your question? What's the difference between a graph which is merely **isomorphic** to a poth or a cycle, and a graph which actually **is** a path or a cycle? If two graphs are isomorphic, and if one of them is a path, doesn't that imply that the other one is also a path?

Comment: If $L(G)$ is bipartite, can you say anything about the maximum degree of vertices in $G$?

Comment: @bof yes the graph is connected.

Comment: **Hint:** If line graph $L(G)$ is bipartite, how many colors are [needed to edge-color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring) $G$?

Answer (score 1):

The "only if" direction: If $G$ has a vertex of degree $k=3$ or higher then $L(G)$ on the edges incident to $v$ is isomorphic to $K_k$ and so is not bipartite.

If $G$ has an odd cycle $C$ of length $k$; $k$ an odd integer; then writing the edges of $C$ in consecutive order as $e_0e_2\ldots e_{k-1}$, then $e_0$ is adjacent to $e_1$ in $L(G)$, and $e_2$ is adjacent to $e_3$ in $L(G)$ and so on. So $L(G)$ has a cycle of the same [odd] length $k$ as well, so $L(G)$ is not bipartite if $G$ is not bipartite.

The "if" direction: If $C$ is a cycle, then $L(C)$ is also a cycle of the same length as $C$. If $C$ is an even cycle then, then so is $L(C)$.

If $P$ is a path of length $k$ i.e., $k$ vertices and $k-1$ edges, then $L(P)$ is also a path, but with length $k-1$ i.e., $k-1$ vertices and $k-2$ edges.

Can you put this all together.